# Working with bits-output in c

Tags: c, binary

I have to say what the output of the program for w = 33. I do not know how to do it. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this without writing the binary representation of each number?

```
void notChicken(int w) 
{
    unsigned int v1 = 0x12345678;
    unsigned int v2 = 0x87654785;
    unsigned int v3 = 0xffffffff;
    unsigned int tmp;
    tmp = (v1 >> 3) | (v2 << 3);
    tmp &= v3 & ~(v3 << (w >> 1));
    printf("%8x\n", tmp);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: As for a way to get to know what's happening, split all the expressions up into their simplest possible sub-expressions. Store each sub-expression in a separate variable. Then use a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring the variables, to see what happens in each step.

Comment: Or if you don't have access to a computer with a debugger, then use *pen and paper!*

Comment: Without a computer the easiest way is converting into binary using pen and paper. At least doing bitlevel operations directly on hexadecimal numbers is beyond __my__ intellectual possibilities.

Comment: Are you allowed to assume a specific size for `unsigned int`?

Comment: @StoryTeller `printf("%8x\n", tmp);` implies that `unsigned int` has 32 bits.

Comment: size of unsigned int is 32 bits

Comment: @WeatherVane - I see only an implicit assumption. This question would have been better served with `uint32_t`.

Comment: @StoryTeller but you *did* ask to make an assumption, not for a definition!

Comment: @WeatherVane - I asked for explicit assurance. Not excuses to justify an implicit assumption.

Comment: *Are you allowed to assume a specific size for unsigned int?*

Comment: If you can do multiplication and division with hex numbers, you can use that `x << 3` is the same as `x * 2^3` which is the same as `x * 8`. Similar `x >> 3` is `x/8`.

Comment: @WeatherVane - And? I know what I said. And I intentionally asked for the more general clarification instead of "is unsigned int 32 bit"? What exactly is this arguing with me for?

Comment: @StoryTeller all I did was to reply to your comment. It is *your* argument, not mine.

Comment: @WeatherVane - The only one being argumentative is you. My reply to *you* was what I meant in my original comment. Then you started throwing exclamation marks and quotes in italic, as if I insulted you personally. What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not a good idea, lets try to break down your operation.

You have given `w = 33`

The last part -

`v3 & ~(v3 << (w >> 1))` is going to evaluate as `v3 & ~(v3 << 16)`

`v3 << 16` is `0xffff0000` and `~` of that is `0xffff`

since `v3` is all ones you get `0xffff`. This will mask off the upper 16 bits of the previous computation.

Now `(v1 >> 3) | (v2 << 3);`

We care only about the lower 16 bits.

`>> 3` is dividing by 8 and `<< 3` is multiplying by 8.

So the result of first part will be

```
0x2468ACF | 0x3B2A3C28
```

Keeping only the lower 16 bits

```
0x8ACF | 0x3C28
```

Finally I don't know how you are going to do the OR without writing the bitwise representation. I can help with the last hex. It will be `F`.

Comment: `C|2` is `E`, `A|C` is `E` and `8|3` is `B` so (if the other calculations are correct): `0x8ACF | 0x3C28` -> `BEEF`

Comment: @4386427 I would have written that, but I don't know how to explain how I got C | 2 = E without going through the bit representation.

Comment: @4386427 also funny that `notChicken(33) == 0xBEEF` :)

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - I think that's the intended pun :)

Comment: yep - a teacher (or book writer) having a little fun. There's nothing like nerd-jokes... :)

Comment: You can explain how you got to 0x2468ACF | 0x3B2A3C28? @AjayBrahmakshatriya

Comment: @Daniel, do you mean the values? That is just multiplication and division. You can use a calculator for the second one. First one can be done orally. Because division by 8 is just removing the last hex and doubling the others and add 1 if the last digit (that was removed) was greater than 8.

Comment: @Daniel, if you mean how I got there step wise, I just replaced `v1` and `v2` with the constants they are defined as which is `(0x12345678 / 8) | (0x87654785 * 8)`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I didnt undersrtand the calculation of 0x87654785 * 8 and 0x12345678 / 8. I will happy to get an explanation.

Comment: @Daniel they are just multiplications. Like you do multiplication in decimal like `25 * 2= 50` or something like that. It is just that the multiplication is done with numbers represented in hex. It may not be possible to do it orally. Or you can covert them to decimals then multiply and convert back. Converting to decimal without a calculator also seems very difficult to me.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya What is the method of multiplication and division at base 16? If you can explain please that I did not understand what you did. Thanks

Comment: @Daniel there is no straight forward way to do it. You should use a calculator for it. Most scientific or programming calculators have hex representation in them.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Thanks. I succeeded to do it in the calculator.